# how can I get driver's version of Network Adapter ? by c# code?

Tags: c#

how can I get  driver's version of Network Adapter ? by c# code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do it via WMI. The [Win32_PnPSignedDriver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394354%28VS.85%29.aspx) class looks like a good place to start, especially the `DriverVersion` property.

I think something like this might work (please note, this code is completely untested and is just an educated guess on how it might work):

```
using System.Management;

...


ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPSignedDriver");
foreach(ManagementObject obj in searcher.Get())
{
    // loop until you find the driver you're looking for (Hopefully you can distinguish this by the DeviceName, DriverName or FriendlyName)
    string version = obj.GetPropertyValue("DriverVersion").ToString();
}
```

Comment: the problem that my drivers is not PnP,
do I have another idea?

Comment: @sari: Well, you've also got the `Win32_DriverVXD` with it's `Version` property as can be seen here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394141%28v=VS.85%29.aspx, maybe that will work? Otherwise it might be possible via INetCfg as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff547694%28v=VS.85%29.aspx.